# Speeding up mysql query with left join and sum

Tags: mysql, left-join, aggregate-functions, query-performance

I try to clean up a very badly coded site that currently gets all products, loops through hem then runs a query on every product to get the stock counts from a second table if the count is greater than 0 then if there is a result echos the product on page.

So while cleaning up the other mess I made a single query (there were 3 separate ones that all did the same thing just different variables) and to stop needing to run 300+ mysql queries on page I added a sum of he left joined tables stock column so I could just access that to check if it was over 0.

However this seems to run 3x slower than running hundreds of separate queries.

The server isn't great so it dies when under load due to MySQL issues. But while I think running less queries would hep the execution time may cause even more issues.

Is there a way of getting the sum of another tables joined column that's not going to slow me down horribly?

**Queries**

Here is an example of the long query:

```
SELECT p.Product_Name, 
       p.Product_Price, 
       sum( i.Current_Stock ) AS Current_Stock 
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN 
                Items i ON p.Product_Name = i.Product_Name 
GROUP BY p.Product_ID 
ORDER BY p.Product_ID DESC
```

The short query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
ORDER BY Product_ID DESC
```

with a second query once per product that looks up the stock of the Items table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items 
WHERE Product_Name = 'Shirt' 
 AND  Current_Stock > 0
```

I just then check to see if the query worked or if `mysql_numrows` returns 0 and either skip or echo the product out depending if any option for that product has stock.

**Products table**

```
Product_ID | Product_Name 
-------------------------
1          | Shirt
2          | Trousers
3          | Dress
```

**Items table**

```
Item_ID    | Product_Name | Option | Current_Stock
-----------------------------------------
1          | Shirt        | Small  | 0
2          | Shirt        | Medium | 2
3          | Shirt        | Large  | 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To help you optimize your query we will need to see both the query and the table definitions including indexes.  Usually judiciously chosen indexes and a refactoring of a query can make an enormous performance difference.

Comment: Sorry, Added on a simplified table structure and queries without all the where clauses to filter categories and ordering.

Comment: SOrry but simplified table structures and queries will not help anyone to help you. A tiny change to a query can make a huge difference at time. YOu will need to post the originals and also the output from EXPLAIN. I have provided an answer below which will provide you partial relief. WIth full information me or someone else will be able to give you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query gathers rows from both tables to make a temporary table of all the combined stuff.  Then your `GROUP BY` shrinks it back down.  To avoid this inflate-deflate:

```
SELECT  p.Product_Name, p.Product_Price, 
      ( SELECT  sum( i.Current_Stock )
            FROM  Items i
            WHERE  p.Product_Name = i.Product_Name 
      ) AS Current_Stock
    FROM  Products p
    ORDER BY  p.Product_ID DESC
```